# Getting current route in pyramid view test

Tags: python, testing, pyramid

I'm trying to test a view in pyramid which uses `request.current_route_path()`.

I'm going with the basic test setup, pretty much straight from the doc:

```
from ..views.auth import signup
...
class ....:
    def test_signup_view(self):
        with testing.testConfig():
            signup(testing.DummyRequest(self.session))
```

I'm using the configuration similar to https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki2/tests.html:

```
class BaseTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.config = testing.setUp(settings={
            'sqlalchemy.url': self.postgresql.url().replace("postgresql", "postgresql+pg8000", 1)
        })
        self.config.include('..models')
        self.config.include('..routes')
        ...
```

but this results in `ValueError: Current request matches no route`

I added the `path="/signup"` param to the `DummyRequest`, but end up with the same error.

My routes are based on uris, not resource-based, so the specific route for testing is:

```
def includeme(config):
    ...
    config.add_route('signup', '/signup')
    ...
```

How do I work around this?

Comment: To which docs do you refer? Please provide a link.

Comment: Also please include your route configuration and how you load that in your `testing.testConfig`.

Comment: @StevePiercy I'm following https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki2/tests.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not super easy to mock `current_route_path` via `DummyRequest` because it relies on an `IRoute` object attached to it named `matched_route` as it's doing `request.matched_route.name` to get the route name and thus the metadata required to generate the route. This object is typically attached by the router when the request is actually matched to a route.

I think you have 3 options:

1. Mock the function on the request object entirely with a version of `current_route_path` that returns what you want. For example `request.current_route_path = lambda *a, **kw: '/path'`. This is great if it's not the focus of your test.
2. Pull the `IRoute` object from the introspector and attach it to the dummy request. This requires learning the introspector api and pulling it from there and setting it as `request.matched_route = iroute_object`.
3. Use a functional test that goes through the router, at which point Pyramid will setup things correctly for you.